# Additive inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

I have the problem of showing that for a field $F$ of characteristic $p$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then the following set produces a subfield of $F$

$\{a \in $F$ :  a^{p^n} = a$}

I have proved the other properties except am having trouble showing the existence of an additive inverse.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that under the hypothesis that $a^{p^n}=a$, you’re having trouble showing that $(-a)^{p^n}=-a$?

Comment: Yes. I can see how it is true for $p$ odd, but not $p=2$

Comment: But in characteristic two, minus equals plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $p=2$, $ch(F)=2$, so $2a=0$, hence $a=-a$. So $(-a)^{2^{n}}=a^{2^{n}}=a=-a$.